# Desktop PC can't see new Nokia Gateway 3.2

Tags: windows, networking

I normally connect to the Internet using a wireless router (Rogers Rocket Hub).

To log into it I use `192.168.0.1` hardwired from my PC through a Netgear unmanaged switch.

Rogers said I have to trade up to a Nokia Gateway 3.2 because they are going to stop supporting the Rocket Hub.

But…

When I unplug the Rocket Hub from the switch and plug in the Nokia I can't get to its interface at `192.168.1.1`.

My Windows 7 laptop can connect to it and my "spare" Windows 7 PC can do it but this Windows 10 PC can't.

I this a Windows 10 Firewall thing or a Bitdefender thing or what's going on?

I'm stumped.

Comment: `192.168.1.1` is not the same as `192.168.0.1`. Are you sure you are connecting to the right address? “To log into it I use `192.168.0.1` hardwired from my PC through a Netgear unmanaged switch.” Are you sure the switch is not getting in the way? It seems like maybe the switch is somehow on a different network range than the new Nokia Gateway?

Comment: Try plugging the Nokia directly into your PC and see what happens. If it works, then the switch is getting in the way. Why? I don’t know. Perhaps the switch is not unmanaged as you state? Whatever the issue if the Nokia directly connected to the PC works, the switch is the culprit and should be investigated.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem.

I issued the following command:

```
ipconfig /release
```

Then:

```
ipconfig /renew
```

I can now see the Nokia Gateway thru the switch.

I cleared the ARP cache as well.

Rogers forgot to tell me this.

It always worked connected directly to the PC.

Comment: Excellent work! Nice self-solved question.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but too long for a comment - please let me know if it's of no help, and I'll delete this.

1. Check the [manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1486573/Nokia-Gateway-3.html) for clues on that issue.
2. Double-check the IP address -- the manual states the default gateway IP address is `192.168.18.1`. Can you ping that IP?
3. Be sure it's not a hardware issue. Boot the Windows 10 PC from another OS on a USB flash drive, such as [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install). If Ubuntu cannot connect, it could be an issue with the network interface controller card (NIC).

Comment: Good answer! Here appears to be a quicker “[quick start](https://wifi-helpcenter.nokia.com/hc/en-us/articles/360056530273-Logging-into-the-web-GUI)” guide.